# Modern Android phones and Project Treble/GSI

Tags: samsung, treble

I am looking to upgrade my phone and want to run Lineageos or similar, but in the last 2.5 years it seems support for new devices has dried up.

I see that there is are "GSI" version of ROMS of interest which seem to rely on project treble - assuming my understanding is correct.

My quretion is this - **Do all Android phones which come with Oreo or newer - and realistically Android 12/13 and a bootloader that can be unlocked support Project Treble/GSI ROMs?**

If not, is there ant list that can show what devices are supported?  (I'm likely looking at a Samsung S24 but could not find anything about Project Treble/S24 on it (but it looks like it does have an easily unlockable bootloader)